# WPF launch Datagrid Interaction.Triggers on specific column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, view, binding

I have recently started using `Interaction.Triggers` and I was wondering if it would be possible to activate the trigger only when clicking on a certain column. In this case, I want it to launch when the user clicks on elements of the `Nom Produit` column (in blue).

The binding is already working great between the trigger and the datagrid. I just want to modify the launch condition of the trigger because now wherever the user clicks in the row (even `Action, Impression/Édition` buttons), it will launch.

[image]

Here is a minified version of my `ProductsListView.xaml`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" x:FieldModifier="public" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="No MAT" Binding="{Binding MATProductNumber}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="0.1*"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Format" Binding="{Binding tblFormat.FormatName}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="0.1*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProductNavCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</DataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a CellTemplate for the "Nom Produit" column and place your Interaction.Triggers there:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nom Produit" MinWidth="120">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Propriete2, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.ProductNavCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This way it will only trigger when the click is on the "Nom Produit" column.
(As shown above, you will have to change the Binding for the Command to bind to your ViewModel).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, that solved my problem! It says I need to wait 19 hours in order to give you the bounty. Will do tomorrow for sure :)

Comment: Glad that helped :)